# How do you describe a slight right/left turn (bearing left or right)?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, inglés

When giving directions in English, we typically say "turn" to mean a full 90 degree (more or less) turn, but a shallow turn can be a "slight left/right" and we might say something like "bear right at the fork in the road." How do you convey "slight left/right" and "to bear left/right" in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might depend on the localization.

In Mexico we say:

> Gira tantito a ...
>
> Gira poquito a...
>
> Gira ligeramente a...
>
> Gira un poco a...

I'm not sure however if any of this sound weird to anyone from, lets say, Uruguay or Argentina.

We also tend to say **Quebrar** (*Break*) when implying a drastic 90° turn:

```
-Quiébrate a la derecha.
```

Answer (score 5):

In Spain:

> Girar ligeramente hacia la izquierda/derecha
>
> Girar levemente hacia...
>
> Girar un poco hacia...

Comment: De hecho, así son habitualmente las locuciones de los sistemas GPS, como por ejemplo el de Google.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativamente a "gira ligeramente hacia la derecha", lo cual no lo he odído nunca en uso común, me inclino por lo que sugiere Laura: "sigue hacia la derecha", con sus variantes:

- continúa por la derecha;
- toma el camino de la derecha;
- ve por la derecha;
- desvíate [ligeramente] hacia la derecha;
- etc.

(Derecha intercambiable por izquierda.)

Desde luego, lo de "hacer una pequeña derecha" me suena fatal y no recomiendo su uso para nada:

- no tiene sentido decir "pequeña derecha";
- tampoco tiene sentido decir "hacer [una] derecha".

Comment: Creo que la respuesta de @lma es la más correcta. "continúa por la derecha" y las otras son confusas, encajan más con dos caminos paralelos, uno a la derecha y otro a la izquierda, donde no hay que girar.

Answer (score 0):

I would translate "slight left/right" as :

```
Pequeña izquierda / Pequeña derecha
```

For example:

```
Haz una pequeña izquierda cuando llegues a la intersección.
```

Another way I would express that would be  `diagonal a la izquierda / diagonal a la derecha`.

For example:

```
Haz una diagonal a la izquierda cuando llegues a la intersección.
```

Te term `diagonal` makes it obvious that you are not talking about the 90<sup>o</sup> turn but rather a 45<sup>o</sup> turn more or less.

**Update:** Another suggestion (mentioned by Javi on his comment) would be: `gira ligeramente a la izquierda/derecha`.

**Update 2**: Dusan suggests `Gira un poco hacia la derecha/izquierda`.

Comment: Maybe "gira ligeramente hacia..." can work. I had never heard "pequeña derecha/izquierda"maybe its use is regional.

Comment: @Javi good suggestion (`gira ligeramente....`) will add it to my answer. As for the `pequeña izquierda` it's probably regional, then. I think it's easy to understand that you mean a `little turn to the left/right`

Comment: I usually just say "sigue hacia la (derecha/izquierda) when it's not a full turn.

Comment: I would say "Gira un poco hacia la (derecha/izquierda)".

Comment: _Pequeña izquierda_ means _small left_. It is incorrect to use it instead of _(gira) ligeramente a la izquierda_ or _(haz) un pequeño/suave giro a la izquierda_. If it is a regional use I would like to know from where (New York?).

Comment: Both pequeña izquierda/derecha and hacer una diagonal sound off to me. More specifically, they sound like spanglish, so there might be speakers in the United States or Puerto Rico that actually say that kind of thing, but I don't think the could be considered standard in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This might be regional from Argentina but for a really slight turn, we sometimes use "tirarse". "Tirate a la derecha" (notice the absence of tilde in "tirAte", voseo conjugation). In other regions they might or might not use this or replace "tirarse" with "echarse". Not sure.

Another possibility is to omit the fact that it's a turn and just use "ir". Something like: "Al llegar a la bifurcación ve a/hacia la derecha".

Also in many cases were "ligeramente" has been suggested, I would also use "levemente" or "un poco" or "haz un leve giro a la derecha".